# Big data table processing with RDBMS like MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle, rdbms

I have two tables Customers and Orders and each has 100 million records.

Now I have to join these two tables on the column customer_id in both Customer and Order table to generate a report. customer_id is the primary key in customer table and foreign key in order table.

I have heard from senior folks that it is close to impossible to do it MySQL(or any other RDBMS) because a single system has to perform this join on a huge volume of data. Is that correct RDBMS like MySQL(or Oracle) are not good for such a large volume of data even for simple operations like join with proper indexes ?

Also I would like to know what data size per table is considered good for RDBMS table so that simple operations like join, aggregation with proper indexes works well ? I know answer may be "It depends" or vary based on number of factors. But consider best possible tuning is done, still is there any broad level standard data size limit that is considered good ?

Comment: Why such a big report? Who's going to read a report with 100M records? At 100 records per page, that's a million pages. You want aggregation. All of the RDBMS dbs today would find no problem with aggregates over large numbers of records - with good indexes. Those and an SSD and you're good to go!

Comment: Anything under INFINITY is good.

Comment: 100kk customers? really? I think it is possible only in a case when the data is extremely de-normalized...

Comment: @Vérace Report will just give aggregated data for 15 days. But search and join has to run on 100M records.

Comment: *But search and join has to run on 100M records.* No.

Comment: Provide DDL for tables. Provide DML of a small sample either here or in a fiddle (dbfiddle.com) or on pastebin. As @Akina points out, with indexes, nothing will have to run over 100M records!

Comment: Are you using Oracle?  Or MySQL?  The Answer will be different.

Comment: 100M rows is feasible, but not fast.  Show us the `SELECT` _and_ the `CREATE TABLEs`.

Comment: @Vérace `As @Akina points out, with indexes, nothing will have to run over 100M records!` What I mean here is , For one table it has to go through 100M records and for join to other table it will use the index(that can be alomost O(1)). DDL are not created yet , this design is under discussion yet

Comment: @RickJames I am using MySQL

Comment: @emilly for the join you describe, it will have to scan 100M customers (that will take minutes, maybe an hour), then lookup 100M orders _randomly_ via an index (more minutes or hours).  Disks are not instantaneous !  Even with caching, CPUs are not instantaneous !  Requesting all of 100M rows is (usually) excessive.

Comment: @emilly Please post TEXT RESULTS of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE customers; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE orders; C) SHOW INDEX FROM customers; D) SHOW INDEX FROM orders; E) your SELECT ....  with the date range  and F) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ........ with the date range 
 for analysis.

Comment: A few jobs ago I worked with a MySQL database that contained several tables with over 100 million rows that joined on each other. I had indexes on all keys, and the queries were incredibly fast. Indexes will save you in these situations.

Comment: @RickJames  What do you mean by `Disks are not instantaneous ! Even with caching, CPUs are not instantaneous` ?

Comment: @emilly - One must expect slow response time from larget data sets _unless_ you use techniques (such as indexing) to avoid looking at all the records.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are talking about performance. There are so many factors/parameters responsible for performance. With no doubt 100 million records are feasible in RDBMS, it depends upon configuration you have made for your server. If we look for some parameters be like :

1) Hardware : Looking into your physical table size, proper RAM allocation is done or not. For feasible amount of RAM proper CPU cores are divided or not.

( Specifically of MySQL )

2) Sort Buffer : Whether optimal values are configured for Sort buffer global variables.

3) Temporary Table Size : Temporary table size should be suitable enough

4) Join Buffer : Join buffer should be configured with optimal value.

And many more parameters need to look in.

Hope this helps.